# Sending file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, sockets, sendfile

Can I send file on one port to more computers at the same time in C#? Like I have code to send by `System.Net.Sockets` on port `1234`and I want to send file to 5 computers. Can I do it at the same time?

Comment: Are those computer in one LAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that if you mean with one port the desitination port...

you will need to use `Async` or `Thread` to make the sending parallel... you will have to deal with correctly setting the `FileStream` `sharing` so the file can be opened in parallel by the different threads.

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx
http://www.csharp-examples.net/create-new-thread/
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/2/

EDIT - as per comment :

it doesn't make a difference... you can use `ThreadPool` and create per destination one work item... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx and http://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool

Comment: Thank you, but if will I don't know to how many computers will i send file?